# decoded PCM by libmpg123 is not playing in audio-track

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, pcm, audiotrack

after so much efforts i am able to decode the mp3 to PCM by mpg123 library, but the problem is i dont know the buffer i am getting is of pcm or not because when i trying to feed short buffer i am not getting any sound in AudioTrack , although i have checked and play preconverted pcm files to audiotrack successfulluy. my code is 
thanks in advance :)

```java
            Log.e("", "" + NativeWrapper.initLib());
            int err = NativeWrapper.initMP3(filename);
            Log.e("", "err  " + err);
            if (err != MPG123_OK) {
                // TODO: Show error
            }
            Log.e("", "file name    " + filename);
            AudioFileInformations audioInfo = NativeWrapper
                    .getAudioInformations();
            if (!audioInfo.success) {
                // TODO: Show error
            } else {
                int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize((int) 44100,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, (int) 44100,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize * 4,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                buffer = new short[minBufferSize];

                boolean first = true;
                signalThread.doNotify();
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                            + "/"
                            + "jumme_out.mp3");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                do {
                    if (ended)
                        break;

                    try {
                        err = NativeWrapper
                                .decodeMP3(minBufferSize * 2, buffer);
                        if (err == MPG123_OK || err == MPG123_NEW_FORMAT) {
                            first = false;
                            track.write(bufferbyte, 0, bufferbyte.length);                              track.flush();
                        } else
                            break; 
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } while (!ended);
                if (err == MPG123_DONE) {
                    track.flush();
                    track.stop();
                    try {
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Now i have my decoded PCM by NDK ,i want to change pitch and speed dynamically... but how would i suppose to work on speed and pitch .. all i can do is change the sample rate in audio-track .. which is only working on KitKat ..
and i have also implemented Sonic-NDK ..which is playing sound with noise..
but the thing Sonic need to feed PCM so i am converting to pcm by mpg123 and feeding it dynamically .. but the whole process is not fast enough and i am hearing a gap in loop..
code is :

```html
void recursive() {
  buffer = new short[minBufferSize];
  err = NativeWrapper.decodeMP3(minBufferSize * 2, buffer);
  byte[] bufferbyte = ShortToByte_Twiddle_Method(buffer);
  sonic.putBytes(bufferbyte, bufferbyte.length);
  int available = sonic.availableBytes();
  modifiedSamples = new byte[available ];
  sonic.receiveBytes(modifiedSamples, available);
  track.write(modifiedSamples, 0, available); // Write
  if (err != MPG123_DONE) {
   recursive();
  }
 }
```

so now i have three queries:
1. is why my audio-track is working fine only in 19 API
2. how would i remove gap and noise  in chunks (code below)
3. is there any other way to achieve operation on pitch and speed dynamically is there any other library or something or what else i should do.

Comment: I don't see you ever calling `track.play()`.

Comment: oh my mistake..thanks u lot sir ..now it works smoothly.